# Spring AOP does not work as expected with the ID type managed by Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-aop, spring-3

I have the following Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_app")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4992188185008895307L;

    private String id;
    ...

    public User(){

    }

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

The Id is of type **String**

I am working with Spring Data JPA, and I have the following:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

}
```

I am working with AOP and I have the following:

```
@Before("execution(* *..UserRepository.findOne(..))")
public void beforeRepositoryLogging(JoinPoint jointPoint){
    logger.info(">>Before {} called", jointPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

It works fine.

But if I change from:

- @Before("execution(* *..UserRepository.findOne(..))")

to

- @Before("execution(* *..UserRepository.findOne(String))")

It does not works anymore. Why?

Until here according with the API:

[JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)

> `Interface JpaRepository<T,ID extends Serializable>`

Where ID according with the API

[Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html)

> `ID - the type of the id of the entity the repository manages`

Remember:

My repository has `JpaRepository<User, String>`, the **ID** therefore is **String**
and the **findOne** method signature is `T findOne(ID id)`. How conlusion, the type of my ID is String.

Therefore what is missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the fully qualified class name?  `java.lang.String`?

Comment: Yes, I did it how you have suggested. Same situation..

Comment: Try explicitly specify findOne(String id) in the UserRepository interface. I think this is due to artificial nature of generics in Java.

Comment: Ah the joy of generics. Due to type erasure there is no `findOne` method with a String argument. hence your joinpoint will not match. The ID is of type String at compile time, after that it doesn't exist anymore. As Aspects are applied after compilation (or in the case of Spring with proxies) it doesn't match anymore. So I would say it works as expected (if you take type erasure into account).

Comment: Thanks by the explanation Marten. Understood. BTW, what you do mean with "if you take type erasure into account"? Thank you.